# Firebase Performance monitor crash always with Retrofit and OkHttp

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, firebase-performance

Im using:

- Retrofit `2.6.4` and okhttp `3.14.6`:

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp"
```

- Firebase

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.4'
```

- Android plugin:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
```

And every time I try to run the app in android 10 in a pixel 3 it crashes with:

Log:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1039KB
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzfa.zzhf(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:75)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzct.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzct.dynamicMethod(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:81)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzfa$zzb.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzct$zza.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzct$zza.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:97)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzct.dynamicMethod(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:82)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzfa.zzhd(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzct.zzew(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:79)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzbg.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzbg.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzbg.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:8)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:2)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
com.lahaus.client E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
com.lahaus.client I/Google Maps SDK for Android: Google Play services client version: 12451000
com.lahaus.client I/Google Maps SDK for Android: Google Play services package version: 19831037
com.lahaus.client I/chatty: uid=10742(com.lahaus.client) arch_disk_io_2 identical 150 lines
com.lahaus.client E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
com.lahaus.client E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.4:5)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:188)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:45)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap.subscribeActual(SingleMap.java:34)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleResumeNext.subscribeActual(SingleResumeNext.java:39)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable.subscribeActual(SingleToFlowable.java:37)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRepeatWhen$WhenReceiver.onNext(FlowableRepeatWhen.java:100)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRetryWhen.subscribeActual(FlowableRetryWhen.java:62)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(FlowableSingleSingle.java:39)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap.subscribeActual(SingleFlatMap.java:36)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback.onSuccess(SingleFlatMap.java:84)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ResumeSingleObserver.onSuccess(ResumeSingleObserver.java:46)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleJust.subscribeActual(SingleJust.java:30)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleResumeNext$ResumeMainSingleObserver.onError(SingleResumeNext.java:80)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap$MapSingleObserver.onError(SingleMap.java:69)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.tryOnError(SingleCreate.java:94)
        at androidx.room.RxRoom$5.subscribe(RxRoom.java:231)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:39)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap.subscribeActual(SingleMap.java:34)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleResumeNext.subscribeActual(SingleResumeNext.java:39)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap.subscribeActual(SingleFlatMap.java:36)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable.subscribeActual(SingleToFlowable.java:37)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:37)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchMap$SwitchMapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableSwitchMap.java:129)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext$OnErrorNextSubscriber.onNext(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:80)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:68)
com.lahaus.client E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMapMaybe$FlatMapMaybeSubscriber.innerSuccess(FlowableFlatMapMaybe.java:175)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMapMaybe$FlatMapMaybeSubscriber$InnerObserver.onSuccess(FlowableFlatMapMaybe.java:397)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeFromCallable.subscribeActual(MaybeFromCallable.java:61)
        at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4290)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMapMaybe$FlatMapMaybeSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMapMaybe.java:132)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.runAsync(FlowableObserveOn.java:407)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$BaseObserveOnSubscriber.run(FlowableObserveOn.java:176)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:288)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:253)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I dont know what to do to use this.

Comment: Please file a bug report with Firebase support.  There's not much Stack Overflow can help you with here. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson I already did that 1 month ago, and I just saw the response from them. thanks for reminding me about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been logged by OP. Here is a link to the issue tracker: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/LRJCoIRSpuY

[This](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/LRJCoIRSpuY/kPKYDsKHCQAJ) works for me as well.

> I also ran into this issue, moving the
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
>
> to be directly after `com.android.application` and before all other
>   plugins fixed it, not sure why that fixed it, but hopefully will fix
>   yours as well?

Comment: doesn't work for me.